# Scrapy: select one immediate following sibling, and return empty string if not present

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div>
    <h2>First title</h2>
    <p>First paragraph</p>

    <h2>Second title</h2>

    <h2>Third title</h2>
    <p>Third paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I need to select the paragraph after a specific title, for example, the first paragraph:

```
response.xpath(".//h2[contains(text(), 'First title')]/following-sibling::p/text()").extract()[0]
```

This gives me `'First paragraph'`. However, if I need to select the text under `Second title`, I would get `'Third paragraph'`, instead of an empty string.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `'Third paragraph'` because the statement you are using is getting the first coming occurrence of `<p>` after `<h2>Second title</h2>`. 
You could do something like the following.

```
paragraphs = []
for e in response.xpath(".//h2[contains(text(), 'title')]/following-sibling::*[1]"):
  if '<p>' in e.get():
    # there is a paragraph after the current title
    paragraphs.append(e.xpath('.//text()')[0].get())
  else:
    # there is no paragraph after the current title
    paragraphs.append('')
```

Comment: I got this error `AttributeError: 'SelectorList' object has no attribute 'getnext'`